# How to compare two data.frames and return rows based on conditions?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two tables, the first a customer transaction list, the second is a product mapping table.

Customer Transaction List:

```
Cust_list <- data.frame(
stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
Customer = c("Mike S.","Tim P."),
Product_ID = c(233,6546)
)
```

Product Table:

```
Product_Table <- data.frame(
stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
Product_ID = c(233,256,296,8536,6546,8946),
Type = c("Shoes","Shoes","Shoes", "Socks","Socks","Socks"),
Category = c("A","B","B","A","B","B")
)
```

I have merged the two tables below (Right-Outer Join), and below is the combined output:

```
df <- merge(x=Cust_list, y=Product_Table, by="Product_ID", all.y=TRUE)

  Product_ID Customer  Type   Category
  233          Mike S.  Shoes    A
  256          <NA>     Shoes    B
  296          <NA>     Shoes    B
  6546         Tim P.   Socks    B
  8536         <NA>     Socks    A
  8946         <NA>     Socks    B
```

I am looking to find out only those `customers` -

- who have not purchased any category `B` product, and
- For these customers I only want to know what similar `type` of product of category `B` they *have not* purchased.
- since Tim P. purchased a category B Product for Type Socks, so he/she should be excluded from the output
- But since `Mike S.` has not purchased any `B` product and only purchased a product of `A` category, I just want to know which similar type (i.e. `Shoes`) of category `B` he/she hasn't purchased.

Based on the two tables above here is the desired output:

```
Customer  |  Product ID  | Type  | Category
Mike S.   | 256          | Shoes | B
Mike S.   | 296          | Shoes | B
```

Comment: Product 6546 is Category B so why is the 2nd row included in desired output?

Comment: I should clarify if they are already purchasing any product from Category B then it is excluded.

Comment: Please provide your code and describe what problem you're having.

Comment: Hi, I've updated the original question with code and additional details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this

```
Product_Table %>% filter(Category == "B") %>%
  right_join(
    Cust_list %>% left_join(Product_Table, by = "Product_ID") %>%
      group_by(Customer) %>%
      filter(!sum(Category == "B") > 0) %>%
      select(-c(Category, Product_ID)),
    by = "Type"
  )
  Product_ID  Type Category Customer
1        256 Shoes        B  Mike S.
2        296 Shoes        B  Mike S.
```

To check let's suppose customer table is like

```
> Cust_list
  Customer Product_ID
1  Mike S.        233
2   Tim P.       6546
3  Mike S.       8536
4      XYZ        296
5      ABC       8536
6      XYZ        233
```

Now the above code will give following output

```
  Product_ID  Type Category Customer
1        256 Shoes        B  Mike S.
2        296 Shoes        B  Mike S.
3       6546 Socks        B  Mike S.
4       6546 Socks        B      ABC
5       8946 Socks        B  Mike S.
6       8946 Socks        B      ABC
```

which should meet the expectation.

Comment: First of all glad to have been of help.  For the revised scenario i.e. additional questions, it is always advised to post another question, with proper examples.  If this answer served the purpose initially expected, please mark it as accepted as usually desired on SO.